# Parse.com - Use the SDK or the API?

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to parse.com

I was given a small code example of what I was supposed to build on.

This example was based on the parse SDK.

I worked with the SDK for a few days and just didn't like it.

Today, I rewrote it using the REST Api and I much prefer it.

Have I done the wrong thing?

Will I find further down the road that the SDK is better/more capable than the API?

I can't see anything missing in the API but then I am new to both the SDK and the API...

Which would you use?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SDK, no doubt. There will be less code and no object mappings etc.

What was it that you didn't like? And what SDK are you using? iOS? Android? JavaScript?

The SDK is tightly integrated and should feel natural to use. And it offers things that you will need to code manually using the API, like using background threads. If you want the equivalent of

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
```

using the API, you will need to manually program the thread handling and callbacks. You will find that the API will result in less code and less pain, I'm sure.

Comment: I managed to get pointers working today. people tell me that getting ACL working might be tricky.

Comment: still working against the rest api. but I can start to see what you mean